# "Sound Settings" menu in Xfce4-Panel does not open

Tags: 15.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, xfce, indicator-sound

The "Sound Settings" button on the "Sound Menu" indicator of the "Indicator Plugin" on the Xfce4-Panel will not open. This button should open `pavucontrol`, which I can launch from the terminal or Whisker Menu just fine. I just can't launch it from the Panel, which is a real pain. Is there any way I can see a log pertaining to the Panel or Indicator Plugin so I can discover what the issue is?

[Here is the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C3Pu.png)

**Update**:

Here's my session environment:

```
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
SESSION=xfce
UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1983
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
SESSION_MANAGER=local/User-Xubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2156,unix/User-Xubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2156
DESKTOP_SESSION=xfce
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
GDMSESSION=xfce
SESSIONTYPE=
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xfce
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-dIizG8qAqw
```

Comment: While [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/629870/37165) asked on "pavucontrol is not launching in xubuntu" and is closely related, I voted +1 because this question asked on the location of log files for indicator plugin, which I see as a unique question. Anyway, I have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the indicator plugin log can be found in `$HOME/.cache` directory.

### Log file location

The file location may be slightly changed in newer releases of Xubuntu. In Xubuntu 15.04, the location is `$HOME/.cache/xfce4-indicator-plugin.log` and the example content as below.

```
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Looking at Module: libapplication.so
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Loading Module: libapplication.so
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Load indicator: libapplication.so
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Looking at Service: com.canonical.indicator.messages
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Loading Service: com.canonical.indicator.messages
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Load indicator: com.canonical.indicator.messages
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Looking at Service: com.canonical.indicator.sound
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Loading Service: com.canonical.indicator.sound
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Load indicator: com.canonical.indicator.sound
DEBUG      Indicator-Application     Connected to Application Indicator Service.
DEBUG      Indicator-Application     Request current apps
DEBUG      Indicator-Application     Building new application entry: :1.29  with icon: nm-no-connection at position 0
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Entry added for io=libapplication.so
DEBUG      libindicator-plugin       Entry added for io=com.canonical.indicator.sound
```

The older log files are found at `$HOME/.cache/upstart` and kept separately as Gzip compressed files for each type of indicator. I had confirmed this for 14.04, but not sure whether this is still true for 15.04 and newer releases, because I only ran above output from Live USB.

In other words, the older log files are only found in Xubuntu that has been installed to a local machine. The Gzip compressed files are likely not to exist on a Live system.

### Sound Settings do nothing

Based on the output from `env | grep SESSION`, the session is `xfce` for the current user. That is the reason why the "Sound Settings" does nothing.

This is also a known issue affecting 14.04 release, which was filed as [Bug #1359249](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1359249) on Launchpad in late 2014. Typical users wouldn't notice this, unless the user selected "Xfce Session" instead of "Xubuntu Session" before logging in to the Desktop.

[image: Xubuntu 14.04 LightDM Test Mode]

### The workaround

Select "Xubuntu Session" before logging in to the Desktop. Then, on Xfce panel, click the Indicator Sound icon > **Sound Settings...** to open the **Volume Control** window as usual.